# IOS setting width of textfield programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to display a picker next to a textfield, when the user starts editig. After editing, the picker disappears.

Therefore I changed the width of a textfield like this in textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{ print ("textFieldDidBeginEditing")
   let newSize = CGSize(width: 90.0, height:  textfield.frame.height)
   let newFrame = CGRect(origin: textfield.frame.origin, size: newSize)
   textfield.frame = newFrame
}
```

In textFieldDidEndEditing the width is reset to the old value.

This works fine the time (beginEditing, endEditing)
In following attempts the with is not changed again (the print statement is reached)

What´s going wrong.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I think, I found the problem. I used some auto layout constraints, which overwrite my settings in the code of my question.
I now edit the constraint in the textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing. If the post is opened again I will post my solution

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine in my test project, try insert textfield.setNeedsDisplay() after set new frame.